# developing phonegap apps for android

Tags: android, cordova

I've developed a few phonegap apps for ios and now I want to create android versions for one of them. The thing with android is, of course, that it is used on so many different devices. I understand that the safest way is to test the app on every single device that I'm targeting, but is there a smart and easy solution to test for as many devices as possible without buying 20 new phones? Is the emulator, for example, reliable?

Any hints and tips from you android phonegap guys and girls out there much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can try Genymotion. It has a wide range of devices and they are reliable as far as I experienced, you can get it here;

http://www.genymotion.com/

Also you can try virtual devices from Eclipse. Plus if you try a few real devices, it would be enough I think.

Comment: Thank's for helping out! I just wonder: in what way does genymotion difer from the android sdk emulator?

Comment: First of all it is so much faster for testing. They are both virtual device emulators after all but I don't know their inner structure. However to be more reliable I suggested testing in both of them. I can tell from my experiences that Genymotion has much more alternatives of phone sizes and models and it works really fast.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, there are hundreds of devices no one tests them all.

The best idea is to test on a few physical devices of varying API level and screen size. That is of course not always possible so best idea is to use the built in emulators.

Android SDK comes with an Android SDK manager, this enabled you to download system images for every API version.

You can then use Android Device Manager to create new emulators, running different screen sizes and images.

This should enable you to test quite comprehensively.

Good luck.

Comment: Hi, thank's for responding! I just tried the emulator with Galaxy Nexus as the device, and the app (ionics starter app) was really slow and sluggish. Is this just the normal feel of the emulator, or is it an indication of someting going wrong, in your experience. I'm on a mac.

Comment: Unfortunately yes, emulators are not super fast. I find giving them a bit of time to "warm up" improves their performance.

Also try tweaking the settings when you create the AVD, they are basically virtual machines, so giving them a bit more power should improve performance.